# link in php/html table from sql variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i have a html table in php

```
<?php
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM recepten ORDER BY datum DESC");



        echo "<table border='1'  class='ms-list8-main'>
        <tr>
        <th class='ms-list8-top'>Link</th>
        <th class='ms-list8-top'>Naam</th>
        <th class='ms-list8-top'>Beschrijving</th>
        <th class='ms-list8-top'>Datum</th>

        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
          {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td><a href='$url'>link</td>";
          echo "<td class='ms-list8-even'>" . $row['naam'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td class='ms-list8-even'>" . $row['beschrijving'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td class='ms-list8-even'>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
          }
        echo "</table>";
        $url = $row['url'];         
        ?>
```

the link `echo "<td><a href='$url'>link</td>";` doesn't work

the name of link is in a sql table called 'url'

the link is in each row different

how can i get this to work?

Comment: doesn't work? what error are you getting?

Comment: I answered this first... How about a vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `$url` is never defined. PHP should be giving you an error and complaining about that. Do you have your warnings turned up?

Do you mean `$row['url']`?

eg:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo "<tr>";
     // I've manually concatenated for clarity.
     echo "<td><a href='". $row['url'] ."'>link</td>";
     echo "<td class='ms-list8-even'>" . $row['naam'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td class='ms-list8-even'>" . $row['beschrijving'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td class='ms-list8-even'>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: thanks, i tried this script before, but i had a space before and after the dot. Thanks for the fast answer

Answer (score 0):

It should be...

```
$row['url']
```

Not

```
$url
```